# How to prove compact regions in surfaces are closed.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

This is problem 4.7.11 of O'Neill's *Elementary Differential Geometry*, second edition. The hint says to use the Hausdorff axiom ("Distinct points have distinct neighborhoods") and the results of fact that a finite intersection of neighborhoods of p is again a neighborhood of p.

Here is my attempt at a solution. At a key step it makes an assertion without proof.

Consider a point p in M-R. To show that p has a neighborhood outside of R, we need a lower bound on the distance of p from R.

For every $\epsilon>0$ the set of all neighborhoods of points in R covers R, so the neighborhoods of a finite set S of points in R covers R. Let q be the point in S that is closest to p. The point in R that is closest to p might be in the $\epsilon$ neighborhood of q. If so, the distance of p from R is greater than or equal to $d(p,q)-\epsilon$. If we choose $\epsilon<d(p,q)$ then the distance of p from R is greater than zero, and there is a neighborhood of p in $M-R$ and so M-R is open and R is closed.

Comment: What is $M$, $R$?  What is the question?  Remember [the title is not the first sentence of your question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10144)

Comment: M is an arbitrary surface and R is a region in M. The question is "how to prove compact regions in surfaces are closed?"

Comment: Let $p\notin R$.  Since $R$ and $p$ are compact, there exists disjoint $U,V$, where $U$ is an open neighborhood and $V$ is an open neighborhood $p$.  Hence $p$ is an interior point of $M\setminus R$...